# Rails API best practices for handling wizard flows, when client is a native mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, wizard, rails-api

Many guides / gems exist to help Rails developers create complex web form wizard flows through HTML (such as [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked)).  However, they often do this by tightly coupling the rendering of HTML views to the Rails app itself -- an approach that's unworkable for a Rails API application, since the backend can only send and receive JSON, and is unable to drive the views of the client.

This presents a dilemma for iOS and Android API clients consuming my API, since so much of their wizard branching logic is dependent on backend database data.

**Question:  What are Rails API best practices when building complex wizard flows for multiple clients?**

E.g. Are form objects still a good idea for Rails API-only app? Are State Machines the key heuristic for simplicity?  Or web components?  Or should my Rails API just get out of the way -- focus on providing basic REST endpoints -- and let my iOS and Android clients determine on their own how to validate and navigate users through complex wizards?!

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In most situations, you would want your Rails server (or any server, in fact) to just act as a REST API service, and let the client-side code (either a single-page app, or an iOS/Android app) take care of the navigation flows and the layout.

In rare use-cases where you want the server to take a call on where navigation should take place, I would suggest you pass a parameter `to` in your JSON response, with some sort of indication, either a fragment, or a route, that tells your client where to send the user next. It isn't a great solution because client-side code should generally be decoupled with server-side code, and with this approach you'll have to manage your routes at both the client and the server ends, but it will do what you want, perhaps.